# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sktime.transformers'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rocket, sktime

I tried importing

```
from sktime.transformers.series_as_features.rocket import Rocket
```

When I run this, I encounter this error ---

```
File "C:\Users\Success\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8440/2082396040.py", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Success/Desktop/untitled8.py', wdir='C:/Users/Success/Desktop')

File "C:\Users\Success\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 167, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:\Users\Success\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
exec(compile(contents + "\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/Success/Desktop/untitled8.py", line 11, in <module>
from sktime.transformers.series_as_features.rocket import Rocket

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sktime.transformers
```

Comment: Your installation is not proper, as it states. Make sure you [installed it properly](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/installation.html), as well as you are working inside the environment you installed `sktime`

Comment: @Kris Thanks for your reply! I installed it through conda prompt by running pip install sktime, ran into an error stating - ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Success\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\~tatsmodels\\nonparametric\\linbin.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions. ------------------------- What do I do in this case? I got the same error while running it as administrator as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package was not installed.

There are various ways one can install `sktime` ([See here official documentation](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/installation.html#installation)). Will leave below two options:

1. Using PyPI
2. Using conda

---

**Option 1: Using PyPI**

For that, access the prompt for the environment that you are working on, and run

```
pip install sktime
```

To install sktime with maximum dependencies, including soft dependencies, install with the all_extras modifier:

```
pip install sktime[all_extras]
```

---

**Option 2: Using conda**

For that, access the prompt for the environment that you are working on, and run

```
conda install -c conda-forge sktime
```

To install sktime with maximum dependencies, including soft dependencies, install with the all-extras recipe:

```
conda install -c conda-forge sktime-all-extras
```

By the time I am writing this, this last one ([Source](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/installation.html#installation)):

> does not include dependencies catch-22, pmdarima, and tbats. As these
> packages are not available on conda-forge, they must be installed via
> pip if desired. Contributions to remedy this situation are
> appreciated.

---

**Notes:**

- In my case when installing following Option 1, I was getting the error

  > ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

  And, for that, running, in the environment's prompt, the following, solved the problem:

  ```
  pip install --ignore-installed llvmlite
  ```

  If this previous one didn't work, other alternatives, such as

  ```
  pip install llvmlite --ignore-installed
  ```

  Or

  ```
  pip install llvmlite
  ```

  Might work.
- If the above doesn't work for Option 2, on Anaconda Prompt one can also use pip so the following may help

  ```
  pip install sktime
  ```

  Note, however, that `pip` doesn't manage dependencies the same way `conda` does and can, potentially, damage one's installation.
- If one is using pip on `conda` as per the previous note, and one gets

  > ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\johndoe\anaconda3\envs\Test\Lib\site-packages\~umpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp310-win_amd64.pyd' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

  Doing the following should solve the issue

  ```
  pip install sktime --user
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem. They have moved the actual location of the module in the library. Trying this path should fix the issue you have:

> **from** sktime.transformations.panel.rocket **import** Rocket

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).